# Redirecting to jsp from controller

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring and passing value to jsp from controller like

```
public ModelMap postquery() {
    logger.debug("in query");
    ModelMap a = new ModelMap("home.jsp");
    a.addObject("listt",postservice.getPostDetailsBean());
    a.addObject("siz",postservice.getPostDetailsBean().size());
    return a;
}
```

It is getting forwared to jsp but the url is different instead of `/web/home.jsp`, it is `/web/postt/getpost`. Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

In spring you can map any arbitrary jsp into any URL path. Typically there's a view resolver involved to resolve the view name specified by controller handler method into actual view (eg: jsp)

Please go through some basic Spring MVC tutorial and sample codes to familiarize yourself

Comment: I used View Resolver so it redirects to proper jsp say web/home.jsp.

Comment: but the url didnt change

Comment: View resolver isn't supposed to change any URL, I think you need to review basic Spring concepts

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to a JSP - say  'hello.jsp' :-

1. Change return type of your handler to String
2. do  `return "redirect:hello"`;

Refer the documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-redirecting-redirect-prefix)

Comment: If i use redirect then values in the model is not getting displayed in jsp